# Sort and dump Mysql fields into csv [python]

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I have mysql database where lots of tasks are stored with the duration times, start time and other kins of fields.

The structure is more or less like:

```
taskId | taskName | startTime | duration | server...
```

What really matters to me is to take the tasks, put all the durations of every task in different columns for every task starting with the taskName and in the last row store the average of that durations, or the formula of the average, I am not sure what would be better.

I am kind a rookie in scripting so I am stucked in handling the csv.readers in python. My idea was to make different queries for every task and write them into columns. Then read the csv, make the new query and append the new data. I don´t think it is the best way but I don´t know how else could I do.

I let you what I have but feel free to give new and better ways please :) :

> ```
> fp = open ("priors.csv","w")
> file = csv.writer(fp)
> ```

```
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT duration FROM table WHERE jobname = 'one_task'")
rows=cur.fetchall()
file.writerow('one_task')
file.writerows(rows)
fp.close()

######################################################################################
cur.execute("SELECT duration FROM table WHERE jobname = 'different_task ")
rows_to_write=cur.fetchall()

fprd = open ("priors.csv","rb")
file_rd = csv.reader(fprd)

file_rd_ls = []
for row in file_rd:
print row
file_rd_ls.append(row)

fprd.close()

fp = open ("priors.csv","w")
file_wr = csv.writer(fp)
count = 1
r_t_w_len = len(rows_to_write)
fl_rd_len = len(file_rd_ls)

result_list = list(rows_to_write)

dumm_string = ""

if r_t_w_len > fl_rd_len:


  for i in range(fl_rd_len):

    dumm_string = row + ',' + str(rows_to_write[count])
    result_list.insert(count, dumm_string)
    count+=1

  while count <= (r_t_w_len + 1):
    dumm_string = '""' + ',' + str(rows_to_write[count])
    result_list.insert(count, dumm_string)

else:

  for i in range(fl_rd_len):
    if count <= (r_t_w_len + 1):
      dumm_string = row + ',' + str(rows_to_write[count])
      result_list.insert(count, dumm_string)
      count+=1

    else:
      result_list.insert(count, row)

rows_to_write = tuple(result_list)
file_rd.writerows()

fp.close()
```

As you see, the names of the tasks are not numerated so I can not just make a loop and take them. I am starting just with the two first task but there are more than 100 different tasks.

PS: I know I am not reading ok the cvs to the list, is there where I am right now.

PS2: I still didn´t attack the average calculation since I am not able to read propperly the database.

Comment: Python doesn't have a `++` operator. `++count` is the same as `+(+count)` is the same as `+(+(count))`, and provided `count` is a number, doesn't do anything. It certainly does not increment the `count` value; you'd use `count += 1` for that.

Comment: Why are you opening the same file for reading and writing at the same time? And why are you keeping the file open for reading long after reading in all of the lines (unless it's to stop those pesky Windows types from using your program)? Why are you opening the files inside an (unrelated) `with` block and then closing them outside of it? And who stole all the vowels on your keyboard?

Comment: thanks Martijn, I changed that already.

abarnert, I had already notice that and I was changing at this moment, I will update the code. The vowels are there, sorry if the code is not so legible :p

Comment: The "with" clause came from a previous try.

Now the problem is in the concatenation of the elements of the string for the list, but I will solve it.

My question for you is if you think there is a better or easier way of dumping the durations to columns instead of making the loop for every taks.

Thanks for the answers.